# overwrite dataframe rows with merge

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am trying to overwrite specific rows and columns from one dataframe with a second dataframe rows and columns. I can't give the actual data but I will use a proxy here.

Here is an example and what I have tried:

```
df1
    UID   B     C     D     
0   X14   cat   red   One
1   X26   cat   blue  Two
2   X99   cat   pink  One
3   X54   cat   pink  One


df2
   UID    B     C      EX2
0   X14   dog   blue   coat
1   X88   rat   green  jacket
2   X99   bat   red    glasses
3   X29   bat   red    shoes
```

What I want to do here is overwrite column `B` and `C` in `df1` with the values in `df2` based upon `UID`. Therefore in this example `X88` and `X29` from `df2` would not appear in `df2`. Also column `D` would not be affected and `EX2` not

The outcome would looks as such:

```
df1
    UID   B     C     D     
0   X14   dog   blue  One
1   X26   cat   blue  Two
2   X99   bat   red   One
3   X54   cat   pink  One
```

I looked at this solution : [Pandas merge two dataframe and overwrite rows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58226481/pandas-merge-two-dataframe-and-overwrite-rows)
However this appears to only update null values whereas I want an overwrite.

My attempt looked this like:

```
df = df1.merge(df2.filter(['B', 'C']), on=['B', 'C'], how='left')
```

For my data this actually doesn't seem to overwrite anything. Please could someone explain why this would not work?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One approach could be as follows:

- First, use [`df.set_index`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html) to make column `UID` your index (`inplace`).
- Next, use [`df.update`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.update.html) with parameter `overwrite` set to `True` (also use `set_index` here for the "other" df: `df2`). This will overwrite all the columns that the two dfs have in common (i.e. `B` and `C`) based on index matches (i.e. now `UID`).
- Finally, restore the standard index using [`df.reset_index`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.reset_index.html).

```
df1.set_index('UID', inplace=True)
df1.update(df2.set_index('UID'), overwrite=True)
df1.reset_index(inplace=True)
print(df1)

   UID    B     C    D
0  X14  dog  blue  One
1  X26  cat  blue  Two
2  X99  bat   red  One
3  X54  cat  pink  One
```

Comment: I like the solution although strangely my values so not get overwritten?

Comment: Curious. Maybe you could double check 2 things. 1) Do the entries in the respective “UID” that look like full matches also actually match; e.g. maybe one of the two contains a trailing space?); 2) Same for the col names: are they full matches, e.g. not “B” and “B ”?

Comment: One other question, can I do this without setting any index inplace?

Comment: Also no trailing space. Seems like it should work but it's no. .update is inplace right?

Comment: Unfortunately not (so, it cannot be a oneliner). That is, you need “inplace” for “df1” (for “df2” you don’t need it, since you are only using that df temporarily inside “update”). But for “df1” it is necessary because “update” is itself an inplace procedure.

Comment: I've got it, this is the issue as I was assigning index inplace and attempted to chain .set_index() into the update itself. Many thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can approach this by using [`reindex_like`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.reindex_like.html) and [`combine_first`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.combine_first.html).

Try this :

```
out = (
        df2.set_index("UID")
           .reindex_like(df1.set_index("UID"))
           .combine_first(df1.set_index("UID"))
           .reset_index()
       )
```

##### # Output :

```
print(out)

   UID    B     C    D
0  X14  dog  blue  One
1  X26  cat  blue  Two
2  X99  bat   red  One
3  X54  cat  pink  One
```

Comment: Thank you Johan, answer undeleted ;)

Answer (score 0):

### Using Update function

```
df1.set_index('UID', inplace=True)
df2.set_index('UID', inplace=True)

df1.update(df2)
df1.reset_index(inplace=True)
print(df1)
```

###### Output

```
   UID    B     C    D
0  X14  dog  blue  One
1  X26  cat  blue  Two
2  X99  bat   red  One
3  X54  cat  pink  One
```

Comment: I like the solution although strangely my values so not get overwritten?

Comment: @geds133 Please recheck if you are running all the lines of code. I have tested it on the same sample data provided in the question.